# Unrecognized selector with array objects.

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector, nsimageview

The NSImageView objects once in the array become strings. How to I convert them into NSImageView to avoid unrecognized selector error generated by the last line?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"chip1”, @"chip2” nil],
for (id image in array) {
[image setImage: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@"..."` notation in Objective-C is shorthand for creating an `NSString`. In the above code example, you're creating an array of `NSString`'s, which is why you're getting the `unrecognized selector` error when you call `setImage:`.

Assuming `chip1` and `chip2` are instances of `NSImageView`, you should be doing the following:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:chip1, chip2, nil];
```

You can avoid issues like this in future, by using Objective-C Generics when defining your array:

```
NSArray <NSImageView*>*array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:chip1, chip2, nil];
```

This would give a compiler error if you tried to add a class other that `NSImageView` to the array.